# Instagram EndPoint: Pagination URL gives the same set of results as previous

Tags: pagination, instagram, endpoints

I want to get the all the media posts for a certain user id. I have used the endpoint:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I am also able to get the set of 20 results in the response JSON. However, to get the next set of posts, when I enter the URL provided in the pagination portion, containing the `max_id` parameter, I get the same set of results and not the next 20. Suggest how to get the next set of posts.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get it now after trying on the Insta API COnsole